# Primitive variable type in compile time

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, primitive-types

Not sure if I am wording this correctly. Please let me know if you require more information.
We have a requirement where we need to determine the type of variable based on a system environment variable.

So, say we have a the following class

```
class Test
{
    DUMMY_TYPE testVariable;
}
```

The DUMMY_TYPE is determined based on a system variable. So when Java compiles, is it possible to have Java use the System Environment variable to determine the type at compile type?

Also, is it possible to set this up somehow on Eclipse, where Eclipse will continue to show me DUMMY_TYPE on the IDE wherever I use it, but when compiling and building it can substitute DUMMY_TYPE with the correct type based on environment variable?

Comment: Cool question.  For curiosity's sake, do you mind me asking what the use case for this is?

Comment: Nutshell answer is no, but without knowing what you're trying to do, it's difficult to know if there's a reasonable alternative.

Comment: This is part of an API that is used internally and interacts with a proprietary system via sockets. The internal system can either stream an integer or double for the same variable. It makes determination of that using the environment variable. So instead of maintaining separate code base, at compile time, if we can determine this, would save a lot of headache :). We were able to achieve this in C++ and C#, but Java has been giving us some grief.

Comment: What you need is a preprocessor! [/me ducks]

Comment: So, what do you do if the system environment variable is changed ***after*** the program has been built? This applies to C/C++/C#, not just the (non-existent) Java solution.

Comment: Once the core system and the API has been built (they are built at around the same time) with this environment variable, the environment variable is not used anymore. In fact, it is not even used in a production environment, only in build environment.

Comment: I haven't worked with the source generation portion of annotation processing, but I'd imagine you could use an annotation processor to do this. Annotation processor tools (APT) run before compiling, but after source parsing, and it allows you to manipulate source code. Anyone out there who could expand this idea with some concrete examples? I'm thinking an annotation like `@ResolveType("env_var_name") Object obj;` that gets turned into `EnvVarValue obj;`.

Comment: Brian, thats interesting. Let me investigate in that direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea.

Make the `testVariable` of type `Object` (or a `DummyType` class which extends `Object`).  Then you can load the variable with whatever data you want using the primitive wrapper classes, based on what you read from your system variable.

So:

```
public class Test {

    Object testVariable;

    {
        String whichType = null;

        //Logic to read your system variable from wherever and store it in whichType

        if(whichType.equals("int")) {
            testVariable = new Integer(intVal);
        }
        else if(whichType.equals("double")) {
            testVariable = new Double(doubleVal);
        }
        //etc.
    }
```

Of course, this isn't Java "figuring out" which type it is at compile time like you want, necessarily (and the assignment would take place at run time, when the `Test` object was created), but it seems like reasonable framework for an alternative.

And you can also set the value of the `testVariable` upon initialization as appropriate, naturally.

Alternatively, you could have a method like this which accepts inputs as a `String` (read from your system variable) and returns it in the appropriate wrapper class of the primitive type:

```
public Object getPrimitiveValue(String type, String value) {
    if(type.equals("int")) {
        return new Integer(Integer.parseInt(value));
    }
    else if(type.equals("double")) {
        return new Double(Double.parseDouble(value));
    }
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approximation for what's being asked.  Also, since the type is either `Integer` or `Double`, the superclass can be `Number`, rather than `Object`.

Comment: Jeff, we did think about this. But, the libraries that we use within the API uses the primitive version of the variables. Hence we couldn't do this for application. Butt I do agree with Nathaniel that this is definitely a viable solution, without our other restrictions. Thanks.

Comment: @user1524088 The fact that they accept the primitive versions shouldn't be an issue, due to auto-unboxing or explicitly invoking the `intValue()` method of an `Integer` (and the like for all wrapper classes).